# Replacement of nth-child to nth-of-type gives an unexpected error

Tags: python, parsing, beautifulsoup, css-selectors

I am trying to get some information from the following web-page with BeautifulSoup:

```
url = 'https://web.archive.org/web/20071001215911/http://finance.rambler.ru'
```

With the help of my browser (Chrome), I copy the selector for the desired element:

```
selector = 'body > div.fe_global > table:nth-child(6) > tbody > tr > td:nth-child(2) > table > tbody > tr > td.fe_col-left > div:nth-child(5) > table > tbody'
```

However, bs4 does not support nth-child, thus I replace it with nth-of-type:

```
selector = selector.replace('child', 'of-type')
```

and apply it to the soup

```
r = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'lxml')
selected_element = soup.select(selector=selector)

print (selected_element)
```

the output is [].
I expected to get some HTML code instead.
What is the cause of such an answer?
Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

In selected `div` it has 2 table and I will select second table

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url = 'https://web.archive.org/web/20071001215911/http://finance.rambler.ru'
heads = {'User-Agent' : 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:56.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/56.0'}
r = requests.get(url, headers=heads)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
selected_element = soup.select('div[class="fe_small fe_l2"] table')[1]

print (selected_element)
```

Comment: edited the answer, it has no `tbody` and user agent must set.

Comment: It does work now, thanks. Still, I'm confused why the CSS-selector does not work in my script.

Comment: `nth-of-type` and `nth-child` is selecting different location of element